# C++ class does action in a background - is it necessary to declare stop flag as volatile?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, volatile

My question relates to using volatile for stop flag in order to stop method of some threaded server.
In some open-source projects I see declaring stop as volatile:

```
class ThreadedServer {
public:
    //...
    // this method will be launched in separate worker thread
    void run() {
        while (!stop_) {
            //some useful work...
        }
        if (stop_) {
            //cleanup
        }
    }
    void stop() {
        stop_ = true;
    }
private:
    volatile bool stop_;
};
```

In my server I declared a stop field WITHOUT volatile modifier, and everything works. So why to make class variable volatile in such concrete situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`volatile` signals that the value of `stop_` has to be read from the main memory every time it is evaluated.
What could happen if you didn't do that, in the worst case, is to run without stopping, because thread1 sets `stop_` to false, but thread2 does only look at his buffered `stop` on the CPU cache.

But keep in mind that it **must not** result in a problem, but **it could**.

Comment: So if **stop isn't volatile**, when main thread calls server's stop() method (stop was set to true), the worker thread (where server's run() executing) may not see it next time, yes?

Comment: correct. it is just like with an [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), but the atomic does also take care of thread safety for writing access. however, even without using atomic the program might work 99% of the time.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately can't upvote your answer as I haven't rights yet.

Comment: @AndreyG.A no problem, if I answered your question make sure to accept it to help future researches ;)